# reduce_mean/reduce_sum axis effect on training?

Tags: tensorflow

When calculating loss, does optimization somehow take into account the axis by which the reduced mean or sum is calculated?

For example...

```
X = [[.1, .2, .3, .4, .5],[.4, .3, .2, .1, .1]] # target Data
Y = [[.2, .1, .3, .2, .1],[.3, .1, .1, .3, .5]] # output data

lossA = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(X - Y),0)
lossB = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(X - Y),1)

errA = tf.reduce_mean(lossA)
errB = tf.reduce_mean(lossB)
```

A shows the sum of the samples per channel, while B shows the sum of the channels per sample, which generates a different mean err.

```
lossA: [ 0.02      ,  0.05000001,  0.01      ,  0.08000001,  0.32000002]
lossB: [ 0.22000001,  0.26000002]

errA: 0.096000008
errB: 0.24000001
```

however if one were to use reduce_mean() for the loss calculation the final mean errors are equal.

```
lossA = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(X - Y),0)
lossB = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(X - Y),1)


lossA: [ 0.01      ,  0.025     ,  0.005     ,  0.04000001,  0.16000001]
lossB: [ 0.044,  0.052]

errA: 0.048000004
errB: 0.048000004
```

regardless of using mean/sum I'm wondering if the optimizer will distribute the error differently to the weights depending on which axis I've indicated.  Or is this simply not taken into account during backprop?

My intuition is that by reducing the sum along the 0 axis the optimizer would know better which path to pass a larger portion of the error along through backprop.  But I may have just thoroughly confused myself and this isn't actually relevant to the backprop calculation.